# StringBuilder.ToString() is adding '\' characters in the beginning and ending of the string

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

`StringBuilder.ToString()` is adding '\' characters in the beginning and ending of the string.

Why is this?

Before calling .ToString() the string doesn't have the '\' character.

Comment: please put the code here so we can see.

Comment: -1 After 790 questions one would think you'd ask less elementary questions, or at least have better writeups. Or even learn to spell check.

Comment: Editors do a pretty good job of taking awful questions and turning them into acceptable questions, so there's not much incentive to improve.

Comment: Yeah, and it’s amazing how many editors do that considering that editing questions doesn’t earn any rep.

Comment: Sure, the question might be phrased in a better way, but it is far from deserving any down- or close-votes. And it is also a "real" question as proven by the pretty good anwsers so far.

Comment: +1 - Although you could of put a bit more information it's still a valid question and difficult to understand if you're not familiar with the debugger.

Comment: It might well be a good question, but we don't really know. Maybe the answers here are to the wrong good question.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/594160/consider-displaying-strings-in-the-debugger-without-escaping

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you thinking of these backslashes here?

[image: Example screenshot showing backslashes in the Watch window]

If so, you are misreading the output: The backslashes are not actually in the string. They are only displayed here to make the representation valid according to C# syntax. If you were to output the string using `Console.WriteLine`, for example, it would not have backslashes.

To be fair, it *is* inconsistent. The debug view for the `StringBuilder` doesn’t have the backslashes, but the one for strings does.

Comment: This is because of the quote you'e added. The "\" is not really present in te string. It's just a visualisation of the debugger. Click on the magnifier and you'll see the real text in the stringbuilder!

Comment: @Kirk Woll: Now with drop shadow! :-D

Comment: Hey, flaggers, Hans was joking, you can stop flagging his comment now.

Comment: @Timwi That is offensive?  You know, he didn't actually downvote.  Click your votecount and you can see this.

Answer (score 2):

[StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) does not add any characters besides those you have appended. Perhaps you are looking at the Debug View of a string created by string builder and [characters which may need to be escaped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) have the backslash (`\`) in front of them for convenience of copying the debug output.

The `\` characters are not actually in the string data itself, but rather part of the **display** of the string.

**Edit: here is a test you can run**

```
private static void TestStringBuilder()
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append(@"""saoetuhasoethuasteuhasoetnuh""");
    foreach (char c in builder.ToString())
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(c != '\\', "EPIC STRINGBUILDER FAIL");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What text do you have in the StringBuilder?

The following code just writes out "hello" for me

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("hello");
var test = sb.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: That's not really an answer as you sound really unsure, as well as the question is just wrong in its current state..

Comment: @Dykam: I think this is a useful answer. It provides the OP with a correctly working sample.

Comment: @Dykam that may be because I don't get the same result as the person asking the question and he didn't give me much to go on

Comment: Quite true, but IMO it feels a bit like a comment.