# C#/.NET: Can I get a string of valid HTML from a Stream?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Ok, so I'm rendering a partial view control in memory that generates HTML that I would like to get to a PDF renderer. The renderer only takes a string as an argument. I have a MemoryStream containing the HTML that I need to get to the renderer.

**This is what I'd like to do:**

- inStream is the MemoryStream of HTML from the partial view.
- doc is an instance of the PDF renderer that accepts HTML as an argument but only as a string.

```
var stream = new StreamReader(inStream);
var html = stream.ReadToEnd();
doc.AddHtml(html);
```

**The problem is that the html string has escape characters everywhere that destroy the HTML.**

(image no longer available)

I'm experimenting right now with different solutions and products in order to generate PDFs from my web app. I had an XSL-FO to PDF renderer set up that accepted a Stream as an argument and that was working just fine. If there is no way to do this then I will just look for another solution. I'm just curious if it's possible.

Thanks!

Comment: If the HTML string contained those backslashes, the debugger tool tip would show a bunch of doubled backslashes, such as `PUBLIC \\\"-//W3C...`. What appears when you open the visualizer?

Comment: @Jeff Everything looks find in the HTML and Text Visualizer, however the rendered PDF looks broken, just as it does when I copy the value from the debugger tool tip and paste it into a HTML file and try to render it with a browser.

Comment: Same misunderstanding as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551898/

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/594160/consider-displaying-strings-in-the-debugger-without-escaping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string does not contain the backslashes. Only the debugger is showing them. The intention was to make the representation valid C# syntax for a literal string. It is a bit confusing, admittedly.